# Fusion Table Icon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have two columns in my fusion table, both store the names of icons. One of the tables is the default icons.

I'm wondering if there is a way to toggle between the two columns to change icons in JavaScript?

Cheers

Comment: How are you displaying the FusionTable?  Are you using FusionTablesLayer on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map?  Or just in the FusionTables UI?  If you are using FusionTablesLayer, you might be able to do what you want with [styleId and template](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style_and_template_ids)

Comment: It can be done: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_multipleColIconDefs.html

Answer (score 0):

1. set up two maps in the FusionTables UI with the appropriate columns defining the icons ([Fusion Tables Help article describing how to do that](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2679986))
2. "publish" the map, get HTML and Javascript, that will contain the values to use for styleId and template for each configuration.
3. call .setOptions on the FusionTablesLayer to change between them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>Astraptes fulgerator- demo data - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.902224578468406, -85.43183000000005),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col12",
        from: "1_DWHpdjPNGQwVZU5OLbMMS-6yrbIY4wTGJoRMLg",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 3,
        templateId: 3
      }
    });
    if (isMobile) {
      var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
      var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
      var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="change A" onclick="layer.setOptions({styleId:2, template:2});"></input>
  <input type="button" value="change B" onclick="layer.setOptions({styleId:3, template:3});"></input>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```